Where can I look into ways of solving the following ODE?
I encountered the equation:

$\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2 = -r^2 + \frac{(2ar)^2}{(r^2+b)^2}$

And got curious as to how could I solve the case where $b<a^2$, $a,\ b$ being real constants. The exercise stated it is $2\pi$-periodic, so I'm thinking doing a Fourier Transform. If any of you guys might know of specialized topics that I might check out in order to solve it, it would be nice. I'm not so interested in getting an answer. Thank you.

What does "solve" mean to you? You could get an implicit solution in terms of an integral by separation. A Fourier series or transform solution can work in the periodicity condition explicitly, but I don't see a way around the complexity of the RHS. If $b=0$, it's a different story.

I was hoping someone was able to pinpoint some method seen in advanced ODEs that could be of help in analitically solving it. By that I meant "finding a series of techniques that could be useful to build a function that solves the equation".

You can get $d\theta =f(r),dr$ for a function $f$ relatively easily and, integrating, get $\theta =\int f(r),dr.$  Then you will have to take an inverse function to get $r$ in terms of $\theta$

This is a nonlinear differential equation so the Fourier transform method is unlikely to be productive.

@EduardoKuri What I mean is that a closed-form solution is unlikely to exist in any reasonable sense. If you just want any solution, there is an obvious one via separation. If that isn't sufficient, it's not clear from either your question or your comment response why that is the case, and what would satisfy your requirements.

do you mean that there is a solution attainable via numerical integration (not closed form)?

I read the suggestions you presented, they were useful. Thank you
